# Understanding Dask's Task Stream

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I'm running dask locally using the distributed scheduler on my machine with 8 cores. On initialization I see:

[image]

Which looks correct, but I'm confused by the task stream in the diagnostics (shown below):
[image]

I was expecting 8 rows corresponding to the 8 workers/cores, is that incorrect?

Thanks

AJ

I've added the code I'm running:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client()
progress(client)

# load datasets
trd = (dd.read_csv('trade_201811*.csv', compression='gzip',  
                    blocksize=None, dtype={'Notional': 'float64'})
         .assign(timestamp=lambda x: dd.to_datetime(x.timestamp.str.replace('D', 'T')))
         .set_index('timestamp', sorted=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Each line corresponds to a single thread.  Some more sophisticated Dask operations will start up additional threads, this happens particularly when tasks launch other tasks, which is common especially in machine learning workloads.

My guess is that you're using one of the following approaches:

- `dask.distributed.get_client` or `dask.distributed.worker_client`
- Scikit-Learn's Joblib
- Dask-ML

If so, the behavior that you're seeing is normal.  The task stream plot will look a little odd, yes, but hopefully it is still interpretable.

Comment: Ok, makes sense although as I'm running on an 8 core machine with 8 workers, I just assumed any subtasks/procs/threads would appear on one of the existing 8 rows.